# Compile error that goes away with comment/debug/uncomment/debug on a single line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

Below is a header file in my program.
I was getting a compile error, saying that I was missing a semi-colon before partyPack.
There is none missing. There were two other errors but I don't recall what they were.

What's really confusing to me is I commented out Pack partyPack; compiled (failed because it was referenced in the .cpp), and when I uncommented and tried again, it compiled and ran.

What could cause this behavior?

```
#ifndef PARTY_INTERFACE
#define PARTY_INTERFACE

#include "utility.h"
#include "Pack.h"
#include "Shop.h"
#include "Assets.h"

struct member
{...};

class Party
{
private:
    const static int TEAMSIZE = 4;
    member team[TEAMSIZE];
    Pack partyPack;
    const Inventory* itemList;
public:
    Party(const Inventory* inputList);
    void newTeam();
    bool load();
    bool save();
    void findItem();
    const void showParty();
    const void showInventory();
    void addToInventory();
    ~Party(void);
};

#endif
```

**Update 1**
I have been able to replicate the error ...
Below is a link to a github repo containing the program's files for reference, feel free to download and debug, etc. The last commit compiled for me in VC++ 2010. I've commented out the portions which require windows.h, it *should* compile universally ... I hope.

https://github.com/dsball/RPGShop/tree/master/RPGShop

**Update 2**
I've isolated the problem to being any time something is changed in one of the header files included in Party.h or in Party.h itself. The simple act of typing int a; and immediately deleting it(with nothing between those two steps) causes the bug. The errors follow:

Error  1  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'partyPack' party.h 30

Error  2  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int party.h 30

Error  3  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int  party.h    30

Then I comment line 30 in Pack.h //Pack partyPack, compile/start debugging (which fails), uncomment the same line and try again, it runs just fine.

**Update 3**
I have replaced Pack with Backpack after learning there is a Pack() pragma, but the issue remains the same.

As was mentioned by others, it does seem like there's something interfering with the definition of Party, but I can't find what it is.

Comment: Using two editors and having your IDE not realize that it needs to re-save a file could cause that...

Comment: This is one incarnation of what's known as a Heisenbug :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Heh. Problematic since it seems to be associated with another bug I was trying to fix when this one popped up. It's making it hard to tell where my actual faults lie.

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior?  Or was it a one-time oddity?

Comment: Sounds like `Pack` was undefined. I had the same thought as Drew Dormann. Do you use an external editor?

Comment: I've seen it twice now, I've been trying to reproduce it; it seems to have something to do with me adding a const pointer as a parameter for another class's constructor (which is the bug I'm trying to fix). When I comment out the changes I made and this bug shows up.

Comment: Pack is defined, and no, I do everything in the visual studio IDE.

Comment: Sorry if it seemed I was implying `Pack` is defined nowhere in your code, what I was trying to convey was that maybe a change you made somewhere else hid the definition (say, by inadvertently nesting it in another class or namespace, as one example). You mentioned you were commenting out some other code, was one of the other errors something like "missing return type - assuming int" or "unmatched brace"?

Comment: There were a lot of those, yes ... but all I changed was parameters for the constructor of a different class...

Comment: Is it a compiler error or an IntelliSense error?

Comment: It's a compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(In later versions, pack has been renamed to backpack.  This answer uses 'backpack' in place of 'pack')

When compiling under G++ (after appropriate modifications to remove Windows-specific code), I get this error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x *.cpp
In file included from Shop.h:6:0,
             from Backpack.h:5,
             from Backpack.cpp:1:
Party.h:30:2: error: ‘Backpack’ does not name a type
```

It looks like the issue is that Backpack.h is including party.h, but at line 5 in Backpack.h, the Backpack class has not yet been defined.  Party.h includes Backpack.h in its line 5, but since Backpack.h has already been included, the #ifndef statement prevents Backpack.h from being included a second time (which would otherwise create an infinite loop of #include statements).

In summary, it looks like this issue is due to circular dependencies.  I would find a way to break the dependency cycle between Backpack.h and Party.h.

In terms of why this is flaky, I'm guessing that VC caches fully-loaded headers as an optimization.  If Backpack.h had been fully-loaded, then this error wouldn't occur.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely Pack is undefined. But there's a header present that likely defines it, so...is it defined in another namespace? ( you might need to use explicit namespace locator like pack_namespace::Pack partyPack; )

Comment: I only made using declarations, no directives, so I don't know what namespace it could be in other than the Pack.h where it's defined ...

Comment: Er ... declared in .h, defined in pack.cpp